# How to use REGEXEXTRACT to remove spesific text between multiple brackets on Google Sheet

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have to extract campaign names from this text:

```
[Ads] | [Bing] | [Leaderboard] | UCL MATCH | 29 September - 31 Desember 2019
```

Ideally, I only want to extract `UCL MATCH` and remove all the others, how do I do this with regex? Or is there some other way to do it on Google Sheets?

I only managed to do this:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(K8,"\[(.*)\]\ | \ w+\|\[(.+)\]\|")
```

which resulted in `Ads] | [Bing] | [Leaderboard`.

Comment: There is not enough information given to be able to definitively suggest a solution. You've shown one string. Are you only ever going to be trying to process *one string in one cell* (i.e., K8)? And if so, will it *always* have that format: `[foo] | [foo] | [foo] | get_this | dd mmmm - dd mmmm yyyy`?

Comment: Yes it will always have that format

Answer (score 2):

Please read my comment to your original post.

However, assuming that your answer to all questions in that comment is YES, this should work:

`=TRIM(REGEXEXTRACT(K8,"([^\|]+)\|[^\|]+$"))`

Answer (score 1):

You can extract the 4th pipe-separated item with

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(K8,"^(?:[^|]*\|){3}\s*([^|]*[^|\s])")
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/91M0l0/2/). *Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:[^|]*\|){3}` - three sequences of zero or more chars other than `|` and then a `|` char
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `([^|]*[^|\s])` - Group 1 (the actual return value): zero or more chars other than `|` and then a char other than whitespace and `|` char.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=INDEX(TRIM(SPLIT(A1; "|"));;4)
```

[image]

for array:

```
=INDEX(TRIM(SPLIT(A1:A; "|"));;4)
```